# How to view missed user utterances in Microsoft Azure Bot framework

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have developed a bot using `Microsoft Azure Bot framework` but now I am trying to see if there is a way to see what were some of the `utterances` that were missed/not mapped to an `intent`. I tried to look around but couldn't find anything related to this. Is it possible to see the log of `missed utterances`?

Comment: I use table storage for this.  If the intent is "none" the default handler for unknown utterances, and I then pass the needed information to an azure function that stores the data in table storage. Once it is stored, it is easy to see what utterances are not mapped.

Comment: @NiteLordz so there is no in-built capability within Azure Bot framework that automatically logs any missed utterances? And is the table storage like any external database or is it a service within Azure?

Comment: The closest I've seen is LUIS Suggested Utterances, which identifies utterances that might not have strong mapping to an intent. It seems like a fair amount of None utterances show up in Suggested Utterances too.

Comment: Chatbase (analytics service for voice and text bots) would do this; it includes a report that groups not-handled messages by intent or apparent intent. A new feature in EAP suggests intents, as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in capability in `Bot Framework` or `LUIS` for this. You will have to log the utterances that go through the `None` intent somewhere or use some analytics service like (App Insights) to get the information you are looking for.

Some initial information at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/portal-analytics-overview

Answer (score 0):

LUIS provides a feature called **Active Learning** where it tracks utterances it is relatively unsure of, and places them in a list called **Suggested Utterances**.  More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/label-suggested-utterances

> In the active learning process, LUIS examines all the utterances that
>   have been sent to it, and calls to your attention the ones that it
>   would like you to label. LUIS identifies the utterances that it is
>   relatively unsure of and asks you to label them. Suggested utterances
>   are the utterances that your LUIS app suggests for labeling.